# I need render bean validation in jsp like html5

Tags: html, jsp, spring-mvc, bean-validation

1. I need check bean validation in client side in spring rest project
2. the validation must be done before posting to server side(like html5)

Is it possible to do that without ajax in jsp pages (like Razor)!

for example: I need to render this in browser:

```
@NotEmpty
@Max(16)
private String password;
```

final render in browser

```
   <input type="text" name="password" required  max="16" />
```

any help appreciated.

Comment: is there solution ? or i have to validate with java script?